# Connect with SSH through a proxy

Tags: ssh, proxy, terminal

I have no real idea what I'm doing here so please bear that in mind if you can help me!

I am trying to connect to my virtual server through a proxy but I can't connect, it just hangs. I'm assuming this is because it's not getting through our proxy.

I have tried exactly the same thing at home and it works perfectly. I'm on OSX using Terminal to connect.

Can anyone advise me how I can get through the proxy with SSH?

Answer (score 129):

Here's how to do Richard Christensen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19162114/32453) as a one-liner, no file editing required (replace capitalized with your own settings, PROXYPORT is frequently 80):

```
 ssh USER@FINAL_DEST -o "ProxyCommand=nc -X connect -x PROXYHOST:PROXYPORT %h %p"
```

You can use the same `-o ...` option for **scp** as well, see [my superuser answer](https://superuser.com/a/752621/39364).

---

If you get this in **OS X**:

```
 nc: invalid option -- X
 Try `nc --help' for more information.
```

it may be that you're accidentally using the homebrew version of **netcat** (you can see by doing a `which -a nc` command--`/usr/bin/nc` should be listed first).  If there are two then one workaround is to specify the full path to the nc you want, like `ProxyCommand=/usr/bin/nc` ...

---

For **CentOS** `nc` has the same problem of `invalid option --X`. `connect-proxy` is an alternative, easy to install using `yum` and works --

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="connect-proxy -S PROXYHOST:PROXYPORT %h %p" USER@FINAL_DEST
```

Comment: I use arch linux with gnu-netcat and the `nc: invalid option -- X` still exists. The solution for this problem is to replace gnu-netcat with openbsd-netcat. See https://pagekite.net/wiki/Howto/SshOverPageKite/#wrongnetcat for details. Thes two versions probably conflict to each other.

Comment: A bit out of topic, but one can also open a tunnel through this connection (remove all '<' and '>' and keep 'localhost' as is): ssh -l <final_destination_user> -L <tunnel_local_port_number>:localhost:<tunnel_final_destination_port> <final_destination> -o "ProxyCommand=nc -X connect -x <proxy_host>:<proxy_port> %h %p"

Comment: Is there any way to connect using GNU NetCat?

Comment: @Petr I never did find a way to do ti using GNU, but feel free to raise a new question for taht I suppose... :)

Comment: @Petr, --proxy command may work for you.  EDIT:  Scrolled down and noticed that an example is in shoaly's answer.

Comment: I got: "nc: Proxy error: "HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden"  
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host" What do I do?

Comment: @user1271772 https://askubuntu.com/questions/413710/nc-proxy-error-http-1-0-403-forbidden and https://serverfault.com/questions/571375/nc-proxy-error-http-1-0-403-forbidden may help

Comment: @rogerdpack. The answer in the second link is to add "-X connect" which is already in the command suggested above (which didn't work for me). The first link seems to point to a different question and it's not clear whether the answer given there is really an answer.

Comment: I'm on CentOS 8 - and it doesn't have connect-proxy :-( ... and my netcat is "Nmap's netcat replacement".

Comment: @echo nc can pass the password in with "normal nc commands" like `-P proxy_username` not sure on password, seems it's going to require it from the command line :|

Comment: ok, thanks. I was trying the general syntax (in accordance with HTTP URL structure)  user:password@proxyserver:proxyport    but it doesn't work that way

Comment: @rogerdpack I got      nc: invalid option -- P    also I could find anything about -P proxy_username   when I did /usr/bin/nc -help

Comment: @echo Maybe ask as a new question, it may depend on your version of `nc` (`man nc` is a good starting reference), good luck!

Comment: For CentOS 7, where I have no "-X" option for ncat, I used the following construction: ssh REMOTEUSER@REMOTEHOST -o "ProxyCommand=ncat REMOTEHOST 22 --proxy PROXYHOST:PROXYPORT --proxy-type http". E.g.: ssh user123@ssh.othercomany.com -o "ProxyCommand=ncat ssh.mycomany.com 22 --proxy proxy.mycomany.com:80 --proxy-type http"

Answer (score 49):

If your SSH proxy connection is going to be used often, you don't have to pass them as parameters each time. you can add the following lines to `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host foobar.example.com
    ProxyCommand          nc -X connect -x proxyhost:proxyport %h %p
    ServerAliveInterval   10
```

then to connect use

```
ssh foobar.example.com
```

[Source here](http://www.perkin.org.uk/posts/ssh-via-http-proxy-in-osx.html)

Comment: i tried that but didnt work. mind you i wasn't exactly sure what i needed to put in but it went something like Host 159.23.191.23 ProxyCommand nc -x connect -x 10.3.50.01:22 %h %p ServerAliveInterval. is that right?

Comment: I just wanted to add that this solution did work perfect for me. My current workplace deploys HTTP-proxies and I simply replaced `proxyhost` by the IP (adding no schema!)  and the `proxyport` by -- in this case -- 8080.

Comment: This answer only can tell someone that the commands you can pass are already (or can be defined) in it's config file, but you have not to explicitly wrote it to a file. You can just pass the argument to the ssh connect command.

Comment: For CENTOS/RedHat: ProxyCommand connect-proxy -H proxyhost:proxyport %h %p.  Please check the connect-proxy options -H/-T/-S and use the right one on the basis of the proxy server. Most likely they would be -H  or -S, try out both combination

Comment: "nc: invalid option -- 'x'" same for -X. I checked nc -h. What these options are suposed to stands for? Can't find how to replace them.

Answer (score 35):

I use `-o "ProxyCommand=nc -X 5 -x proxyhost:proxyport %h %p"` ssh option to connect through socks5 proxy on OSX.

Comment: Your answer is the only one that worked on **macOS 1.12**. I added it in my ssh config:
`ProxyCommand nc -X 5 -x proxyhost:proxyport %h %p`

Comment: Works perfectly on Ubuntu 16.04 Thank you!

Answer (score 27):

Just a remark to [@rogerdpack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23616021/4575793): for windows platform it is really hard to find a **nc.exe** with `-X(http_proxy)`, however, I have found **nc** can be replaced by **ncat**, full example as follows:

```
Host github.com
     HostName github.com
         #ProxyCommand nc -X connect -x 127.0.0.1:1080 %h %p
         ProxyCommand ncat --proxy 127.0.0.1:1080 %h %p
     User git
     Port 22
     IdentityFile D:\Users\Administrator\.ssh\github_key
```

and **ncat** with `--proxy` can work perfectly.

Comment: If you use ncat your sysadmins will pounce on you.

Answer (score 10):

For windows, @shoaly parameters didn't completely work for me. I was getting this error:

```
NCAT DEBUG: Proxy returned status code 501.
Ncat: Proxy returned status code 501.
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I wanted to ssh to a REMOTESERVER and the SSH port had been closed in my network. I found two solutions but the second is better.

- To solve the problem using Ncat:

  1. I downloaded [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/download/), run and wait to connect.
  2. I got [Ncat](https://nmap.org/dist/ncat-portable-5.59BETA1.zip) from [Nmap distribution](https://nmap.org/dist/) and extracted `ncat.exe` into the current directory.
  3. SSH using Ncat as ProxyCommand in [Git Bash](https://gitforwindows.org/) with addition `--proxy-type socks4` parameter:

     ```
     ssh -o "ProxyCommand=./ncat --proxy-type socks4 --proxy 127.0.0.1:9150 %h %p" USERNAME@REMOTESERVER
     ```

     Note that this implementation of Ncat does not support socks5.
- **THE BETTER SOLUTION**:

  1. Do the previous step 1.
  2. SSH using connect.c as ProxyCommand in Git Bash:

     ```
     ssh -o "ProxyCommand=connect -a none -S 127.0.0.1:9150 %h %p"
     ```

     Note that connect.c supports socks version 4/4a/5.

To use the proxy in `git` commands using ssh (for example while using GitHub) -- assuming you installed Git Bash in `C:\Program Files\Git\` -- open `~/.ssh/config` and add this entry:

```
host github.com
    user git
    hostname github.com
    port 22
    proxycommand "/c/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin/connect.exe" -a none -S 127.0.0.1:9150 %h %p
```

Comment: It works, but you need to run git  command in mingw shell instead of windows command line

Comment: Sofair is right. Instead of `127.0.0.1`, you can also use `localhost`

Answer (score 4):

I use `proxychains ssh user@host`; from [proxychains-ng](https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng).
By default it uses a **socks4** proxy at `127.0.0.1:9050` but it can be changed in the conf file `/etc/proxychains.conf` or you can specify another conf file like this: `proxychains -f custom.conf`

Comment: `proxychains` is also usefull with authenticated socks proxy where `nc` cannot handle it.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this after OpenSSH 7.3 is with ProxyJump:

```
ssh USERNAME@HOSTNAME -J PROXYHOSTNAME
```

which is short hand for the ProxyCommand below (which works on older clients):

```
ssh USERNAME@HOSTNAME -o "ProxyCommand=ssh PROXYHOSTNAME -W %h:%p"
```

Or in your ssh config file ($HOME/.ssh/config):

```
Host HOSTNAME
User USERNAME
ProxyCommand ssh PROXYHOSTNAME -W %h:%p
```

The oldest clients require the use of netcat.  YMMV depending on the version of netcat and options supported (see other answers).

Comment: Your answer is the better option according to the [OpenSSH wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts). And almost everyone should have OpenSSH > 7.3 by now, which was released August 2016! However, it did not work in my case, saying `Squid does not support some access protocols. For example, the SSH protocol is currently not supported`.

Comment: Squid is a web proxy, and it's telling you it doesn't know how to do SSH.  You just proxy SSH connections through an SSH server instead, for example through a bastion host.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ which nc
/bin/nc

$ rpm -qf /bin/nc
nmap-ncat-7.40-7.fc26.x86_64

$ ssh -o "ProxyCommand nc --proxy <addr[:port]> %h %p" USER@HOST

$ ssh -o "ProxyCommand nc --proxy <addr[:port]> --proxy-type <type> --proxy-auth <auth> %h %p" USER@HOST
```

Comment: ssh -o  "ProxyCommand nc --proxy <addr[:port]> %h %p" USER@HOST

Comment: what about adding some info about how this works? It showed in the LQP

Answer (score 3):

```
ProxyCommand nc -proxy xxx.com:8080 %h %p
```

remove `-X connect` and use `-proxy`  instead.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I solved it, hoping to help others later.

My system is debian 10, and minimal installation.

I also have the same problem like this.

```
git clone git@github.com:nothing/nothing.git
Cloning into 'nothing'...
nc: invalid option -- 'x'
nc -h for help
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Or

```
git clone git@github.com:nothing/nothing.git
Cloning into 'nothing'...
/usr/bin/nc: invalid option -- 'X'
nc -h for help
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So, I know the nc has different versions like `openbsd-netcat` and `GNU-netcat`, you can change the nc in debian to the openbsd version, but I choose to change the software like `corkscrew`, because the names of the two versions of nc in system are same, and many people don’t understand it well. My approach is as follows.

```
sudo apt install corkscrew
```

Then.

```
vim ~/.ssh/config
```

Change this file like this.

```
Host github.com
    User git
    ProxyCommand corkscrew 192.168.1.22 8118 %h %p
```

`192.168.1.22` and `8118` is my proxy server's address and port, you should change it according to your server address.

It's work fine.

Thanks [@han](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1840385/han).

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 and DietPi. It's a bit pity that credentials must be stored in an external file.

Answer (score 2):

edit config file in:

```
.ssh/config
```

```
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    Port 22
    ProxyCommand nc -X 5 -x 192.168.49.1:8000 %h %p
```

and test:

```
ssh -T git@github.com

Hi [username]! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using the following lines in my `.ssh/config` (which can be replaced by suitable command line parameters) under Ubuntu

```
Host remhost
  HostName      my.host.com
  User          myuser
  ProxyCommand  nc -v -X 5 -x proxy-ip:1080 %h %p 2> ssh-err.log
  ServerAliveInterval 30
  ForwardX11 yes
```

When using it with Msys2, after installing `gnu-netcat`, file `ssh-err.log` showed that option `-X` does not exist. `nc --help` confirmed that, and seemed to show that there is no alternative option to handle proxies.

So I installed `openbsd-netcat` (`pacman` removed `gnu-netcat` after asking, since it conflicted with `openbsd-netcat`). On a first view, and checking the respective man pages, `openbsd-netcat` and Ubuntu `netcat` seem to very similar, in particular regarding options `-X` and `-x`.
With this, I connected with no problems.

Comment: where `1080` can be a `socks5 port`.

Answer (score 1):

to connect to SOCKS5 proxy, simply run

```bash
ssh user@destination -o "ProxyCommand=nc -X 5 -x proxyhost:proxyport %h %p"
```

**OR** add proxy settings to `.ssh/config`

```yaml
Host destinaion_host
    HostName destinaion_host
    User ali
    ProxyCommand nc -X 5 -x proxyhost:proxyport %h %p
    ServerAliveInterval 60
    ServerAliveCountMax 10
```

then you can simply run `ssh destinaion_host`

with special thanks to @maxim-k

Answer (score 0):

In my case since I had a jump host or Bastion host on the way, and because the signatures on these bastion nodes had changed since they were imported into known_hosts file, I just needed to delete those entries/lines from the following file:

```
/Users/a.abdi-kelishami/.ssh/known_hosts
```

From above file, delete those lines referring to the bastion hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Try  `-o "ProxyCommand=nc --proxy HOST:PORT %h %p"` for command in question. It worked on OEL6 but need to modify as mentioned for OEL7.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody on CentOS / RHEL get

```
nc: invalid option -- 'X'
```

use this ProxyCommand

```
ProxyCommand nc --proxy  HOST:PORT --proxy-type http %h %p
```

Comment: This was already [mentioned in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23616021/4575793) and also applies to *OS X*