# PHPSeclib Proxy send username and password as arguments

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib, http-tunneling

Im using PHPSECLIB to send a file and a XML to a SFTP server.
In this case the server im trying to reach is outside my work network. 
To connect to the internet outside we have a proxy to do that.
What i need to do is configure the proxy of this connection to the one i need.

**EDIT --**

I have the following code, how can i pass the username and password of my proxy ?

```
   $proxyHost = '******'                             

    $fsock = fsockopen($proxyHost, $proxyPort); 
    $address = '*****'; 
    $port = '*****';
    $request = "CONNECT $address:$port HTTP/1.0\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\n\r\n"; 

    if(fputs($fsock, $request) != strlen($request)) {
        exit("premature termination"); 
    }
    $response = fgets($fsock); 

    $sftp   = new SFTP($fsock);

    .......
```

Comment: Pro Tip: If your question does not come with a code example, it is probably not On Topic for StackOverflow

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't connect directly to the SFTP server? Are you looking more for a VPN maybe?

Comment: My work connection as a proxy that refuse me to connect to the SFTP server. We have another proxy to connect to the public internet outside and i need to configure that some how .. sorry about the bad post. @molamk

Comment: Do you want to connect from outside to an SFTP server in your work network?

Comment: No. I want to connect to an outside SFTP server with my work proxy settings that allow me to do that. @molamk

Comment: This is too broad of a question, you need to provide more details to have this answered. Also this looks like a system administration issue, so maybe look into https://serverfault.com

Comment: Perhaps see here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19161960/3392762

Comment: Im using PHPSECLIB to send a file via SFTP. I want to connect to a server that cant be reach due to security from my company. We have a proxy that allow us to connect to the internet outside our network. I need to configure that to send the file via SFTP. @molamk

Comment: @molamk do you understand better now my question?

Comment: I don't, sorry. Try to look where @Progrock pointed, and good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/1339#issuecomment-462224179:

> With authorization:
>
> ```
> $fsock = fsockopen('127.0.0.1', 80, $errno, $errstr, 1);
> if (!$fsock) {
>     echo $errstr; exit;
> }
> fputs($fsock, "CONNECT website.com:22 HTTP/1.0\r\n");
> fputs($fsock, "Proxy-Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode('user:pass') . "\r\n");
> fputs($fsock, "\r\n");
> while ($line = fgets($fsock, 1024)) {
>     if ($line == "\r\n") {
>         break;
>     }
>     //echo $line;
> }    
> $ssh = new Net_SSH2($fsock);
> $ssh->login('user', 'pass');
> echo $ssh->exec('ls -latr');
> ```
>
> > If that doesn't work then run the script and tell me what the headers you get back are. Digest authentication is more of a PITA then Basic but it's not impossible.
>
> > More info on how authorization works with HTTP proxies:
>
> https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.3

Comment: thx for the reply. In fact that issue from github was created by me.