# Is it possible to create a proxy in Remote-SSH Visual Studio Code?

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, remote-access, vscode-remote

I need to connect via REMOTE-SSH in Visual Studio Code to a machine with ssh but from a specific machine in which I have previously connected through ssh to.

I can connect to the first machine with no problem, the problem is when I am logged in the first machine and I try to connect to the second it doesn't let me. I have been looking but what I can only find is examples showing how to connect only to one machine without passing through an other one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to a partner, I have found a solution and it consists in changing a little bit the config file from ssh

As I am using VS Code in Windows and I wanted not to use netcat I've implemented the next command to create a proxy:

```sh
Host <target-machine-name>
HostName <target-machine-ip>
User <user>
ProxyCommand C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -q -x <proxy-machine-name> -W %h:22
```

Hope it can help someone else with the same issue.

Comment: Worked for me. Config file is in ~\.ssh directory. You may need to specify the user for the "<proxy-machine-name>" part of the example, e.g. "user@ipAddress".

Comment: On linux, almost the same command: `ProxyCommand ssh -q -x <proxy-machine-name> -W %h:22`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41021069/8620214 works for me

Answer (score 6):

If you are using macOS and want to ssh to machine `1.1.1.1:2222` under socks proxy(`127.0.0.1:1080`), then you can use the below configuration:

```
Host 1.1.1.1
    HostName 1.1.1.1
        ProxyCommand nc -X 5 -x 127.0.0.1:1080 %h %p 
    Port 2222
    User YourName
```

If you are using http proxy or using Windows(Linux), go to check [Connect with SSH through a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161960/connect-with-ssh-through-a-proxy) . Then replace the corresponding `ProxyCommand`.

Hope this could help you.