# Connect github failed with http proxy

Tags: github, ssh

I Can not connect to GitHub by ssh.
We are using the http proxy which port is 8000.

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
ssh: connect to host ssh.github.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

What is missing in our configuration?

Comment: "We are using the http proxy which port is 8000." What do you mean by this? It appears from the error message that you're not using any proxy. Please [edit] your question to include anything from your .ssh/config file which is relevant to connecting to github.

Answer (score 1):

Using [SSH through HTTP proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19161960/6309) would work in your case only if you define directives in `~/.ssh/config`, such as:

```
host github.com
    user git
    hostname github.com
    port 22
    proxycommand "/c/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin/connect.exe" -a none -S 127.0.0.1:8000 %h %p
```

And, in a `git bash` session (not CMD)

```
ssh -T github.com
```

(no need for `git@`, since the .ssh/config file specifies the "`User git`")